Tag suggestion for: "ESP"
Extrasensory perception or ESP includes reception of information not gained through the recognized physical senses but sensed with the mind.
Parapsychology is the study of paranormal psychic phenomena, including ESP.
See also: Tag proposal for "parapsychology".
From World War II until the 1970s the U.S. government occasionally funded ESP research. When the US intelligence community learned that the USSR and China were conducting ESP research, it became receptive to the idea of having its own competing psi research program. (Schnabel 1997)


The problem of extra-sensory perception (ESP) is engaging increasing
  interest in scientific circles, both in America and the Soviet Union,
  as well as Western Europe. The experiments carried out over the last
  decades have accumulated a formidable array of evidence that ESP
  actually takes palce. Since these phenomena are at first sight
  inexplicable in the context of contemporary science this gives rise to
  the problem. How are we to account for them? A few die-hard Newtonian
  mechanists claim that the scientists concerned have all been guilty of
  deliberate fraud. Other scientists are convinced by the evidence and
  claim that ESP has already been established. [...] What is apparent is
  that fewer and fewer scientists are merely uninterested.

Source: Science and ESP edited by J R Smythies

ESP and the Brain: Current Status by Edwin C. May

ABSTRACT: Serious research into extrasensory perception (ESP) has been
  conducted since the 1930's, and a number of different protocols have
  been established to elicit the phenomenon. The large database to date
  has been analyzed by critics and statisticians alike, and the
  consensus is that the result meets generally accepted criteria for
  evidence of a statistically based, information transfer anomaly. We
  provide a brief overview of three of the most common procedures and
  their results as the basis for the justification to engage in a search
  for a central nervous system (CNS) correlate to ESP. Read more.


The American Institutes for Research Review of the Department of Defense's STARGAT Program: A Commentary by Edwin C. May

ABSTRACT: As a result of a Congressionally Directed Activity, the
  Central Intelligence Agency (CIA) conducted an evaluation of a
  24-year, government-sponsored program to investigate ESP and its
  potential use within die intelligence community. The American
  Institutes for Research (AIR) was contracted to conduct the review of
  both research and operations. Read more.


Quotes by Edgar Mitchell, American pilot, retired Captain in the United States Navy and NASA astronaut:

“The subject of the societies’ concern can be broadly classified as
  Extrasensory Perception (ESP, psychokinesis (PK), and survival
  phenomena (theta). Collectively, they are referred to as psi, the
  twenty-third letter of the Greek alphabet and the first letter in the
  Greek word for “psyche”, meaning “mind” or “soul.” - Mitchell
“Telepathy, for example, had been extensively studied and documented
  for a century. The work of J.B. Rhine, Rene Warcollier, S.G. Soal, and
  many others, including the astounding experiment between Harold
  Sherman and Sir Hubert Wilkins in the Arctic, could leave no doubt
  about its existence.” - Mitchell
“ESP is a psychic event in which information is transmitted through
  channels outside the known sensory channels, either in waking
  consciousness, trance, or dreams.” - Mitchell

H.J. Eysenck, head of the Department of Psychology at Maudsley Hosptial in London:

“Unless there is a gigantic conspiracy involving 30 University
  departments all over the world, and several hundred highly respected
  scientists in various fields, many of them originally hostile to the
  claims of the psychic researchers, the only conclusion the unbiased
  observer can come to must be that there are people who obtain
  knowledge existing either in other people’s minds, or in the outer
  world, by means yet unknown to science.”


Suggested questions which can be tagged with ESP:

Is there evidence that brain and mind are separate?
What is the difference between hypnosis and meditation?



ESP is not a good tag for either of those questions you suggest. At most the tag would legitimize answers that mention ESP as a way of addressing the questions, which are not about ESP. Given the lack of scientific basis for ESP, this would be misleading.

-1 ESP is pseudoscience, and this is a science forum; we do not want to encourage such questions here.

ESP research was brought into the spotlight by Daryl Bem's 2011 Feeling the Future paper. 
Replication attempts [1], [2] of the findings have failed to find support for the claims of Psi phenomena reported in (Bem 2011).
As far as I know, there is no known replicable result that gives positive evidence for ESP-related phenomena.
It's clearly still something that is discussed within not only the larger community, but specifically in literature relevant to cognitive science. However, this probably warrants a larger discussion on how to handle topics that have no solid scientific basis. 

Good answer. Also a good citation here http://drsmorey.org/bibtex/upload/Rouder:Morey:2011a.pdf

question: how would you feel about the tags "phrenology" or "free will". phrenology has no solid scientific basis, while the concept of free will, well, one wonders how a study into that could be replicable.

A tag "parapsychology" seems better to me, as it is broader, and that kind of questions are not so common (but they do exist and they are not off-topic regarding how they were answered on this site).
